# Windows PDF API rendering on Surface 2 RT bug

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

For the past couple of month, I’ve been working on an application that uses the Windows 8.1 PDF API. It has been working wonderfully on a wide range of devices including :

- My development PC running 8.1 Pro
- A laptop (not touch-enabled) running Windows 8.1 Pro
- A virtual machine running Windows 8.1 Pro
- A virtual machine running Windows 8.1 Enterprise
- A virtual machine running Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry Pro
- A mini-pc running Windows 8.1 Pro
- A Samsung tablet running Windows 8.1 Home

However, we recently bought two Surface 2 RT meant to run this application and we are now facing a weird problem. I have narrowed down the problem to the PDF API. In the PNGs bellow you will see that there is some weird behavior with the rendering causing some blank zones in the resulting image. It seems to work fine when I’m staying close to the “original” size (the size I would get without specifying any in the PdfPageRenderOptions, which isn’t really “original” considering it changes from one device to another). However, if I try to render a somewhat larger image from the PDF, this is the result.

***Renders:*** http://postimg.org/gallery/226weuga/

***Surface RT device***

- **DebugOriginal_Surface.png**: The desired behavior when not zoomed. This is what I get on the Surface RT device.
- **DebugZoom_Surface.png**: The problematic behavior when zoomed. This is what I get on the Surface RT device.
- **AnotherZoomLevel_Surface.png**: Another problematic behavior when further zoomed. This is what I get on the .

***Any other devices***

- **DebugZoomed_DevMachine.png**: The desired behavior when zoomed. This is what I get on any Windows non-RT devices.
- **DebugOriginal_DevMachine.png**: The desired behavior when not zoomed. This is what I get on any Windows non-RT devices.

I stripped down my code to make sure it wasn’t a UI problem or the way I cached the pdf files, etc. My code is now pretty straight forward as the following sample shows:

```
var pdfFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(NavigationService.Drawing.Path);
_pdfDoc = await PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(pdfFile);

if (_pdfDoc.PageCount > 0)
{
    StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
    StorageFile pngFileOriginal = await folder.CreateFileAsync("DebugOriginal_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    StorageFile pngFileZoomed = await folder.CreateFileAsync("DebugZoomed_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await pngFileOriginal.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        await _pdfDoc.GetPage(0).RenderToStreamAsync(fileStream);
        await fileStream.FlushAsync();
    }

    using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await pngFileZoomed.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        await _pdfDoc.GetPage(0).RenderToStreamAsync(fileStream, new PdfPageRenderOptions { DestinationWidth = 2000 });
        await fileStream.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

Is this a problem of the API or is it on my end?

***Edit***

Microsoft's PDF API sample (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PDF-viewer-sample-85a4bb30) does the same thing on the Surface 2 RT device.

***Edit 2***

The bug is present on the Surface 2 RT but NOT the Surface 1 RT. This is clearly a hardware issue.

Comment: Did you mean to include links to the images?

Comment: Not that this helps, but it looks like a display driver issue at first glance.

Comment: Display drivers could affect the PDF rendering API? Also, it's a brand new Surface 2 fully updated. Haven't touched any drivers but wouldn't Microsoft make sure to push the drivers as windows updates? And if not, is it even possible to update drivers on a RT device?

Comment: Sure, any rendering, including Zoom could be affected by a display driver glitch. The fact that it's only happening on particular devices makes me think it's display related. I don't see how your code could cause it.

Comment: Also important to note, it is the only ARM/RT device we tried the application on.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Even Microsoft's sample has this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix has been released for this issue included in the Windows May update available at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2955164

Comment: This name seems familiar... but it ended with @microsoft.com last time I saw it ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug with the API regarding the device's DPI. Reducing de DPI / resolution solves the issue. They are now working on a fix.

Comment: The bug is still active in Windows 8.1 Update 1, do you know if they are still working on it? Do you know if there is a link to Microsoft Connect regarding the issue?

Comment: @StrAbZ It has been fixed. Look at Shalu Gupta's answer.